# Is JS based on media query working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have the following code that I only need to work at 767px wide and below (mobile)

```
$(window).resize(function(){     

   if ($('#home-container').width() == 767 ){

          var totalCount;   //Keeps track of the total number of li's, shown or hidden.
          var currentCount; //Keeps track of the number of li's currently shown.

          $(document).ready(function () {
          //Count how many li's there are in total.
          totalCount  = $('.thumbnails li').size();
          //Start by showing three of them.
          currentCount = 3;
          adjustLiShown();

          $('#loadMore').click(function () {
          //Increase by three and update.
          currentCount += 3;
          adjustLiShown()
       });

       $('#showLess').click(function () {
       //Decrease by three and update.
       currentCount -= 3;
       adjustLiShown()
      });
  });

  function adjustLiShown() {
  //Hide all and then show the one with index under total count.

  $('.thumbnails li').hide().filter(':lt(' + currentCount + ')').show();
  //Only show "load more" if we haven't reached the total yet.

  $('#loadMore').toggle(currentCount < totalCount);
  //Only show "show less" if we are above the starting number.
  $('#showLess').toggle(currentCount > 3);
  }

  }

  });
```

I've also added [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#downloads) to try and help me test and it detects the size of the window successfully. But the li items dont show just 3 at the breakpoint as the code intends `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)` (even upon refresh)

Have I detected the window width properly? Is there something wrong with this JS? I'm not showing any errors in the console.

I have a link to the site hosted on my server. http://gretchenward.com/SL2/

At 767px and below only 3 of those li items should show. Thanks

EDIT: I have just decided to wrap my code in

```
`$(document).ready(function() {      
var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 767px)");

if (isMobile.matches) {`
```

It works for me.

Comment: Have you tried the webtools that Chrome and Firefox have that let you change the view port size?

Comment: You have far greater problems with your code. You are going to create lots of event handlers with this that will create a memory leak.

Comment: @lostPixels do you have a solution?

Comment: I would start another question, it's out of the scope of this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Device Mode & Mobile Emulation using Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]
<sub>(source: [chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode-files/device-mode-initial-view.png))</sub>

**You can use device mode to:**

- Test your **responsive designs by emulating different screen sizes** and resolutions, including Retina displays.
- Evaluate your site's performance using the network emulator, without affecting traffic to other tabs.
- Visualize and **inspect CSS media queries**.
- Accurately simulate device input for touch events, geolocation, and device orientation.
- Enhance your current debugging workflow by combining device mode with the existing DevTools.

Turn on device mode by pressing the Toggle device mode toggle device mode icon off icon. When device mode is enabled, the icon turns blue and the viewport transforms into a device emulator.

You can also toggle device mode on and off using the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on Mac.

Comment: Thanks I've tried this so I guess the real issue is my code must not be working.

Comment: 1 second I am uploading to my personal server, I will edit the original post and provide a link.

Comment: @gwar9 Works fine. I got two alerts, one saying less than and one saying more than.

Comment: that would be the enquire.js / is the .width attribute in my code good to go?

Comment: Yes... You are... `:)`

Comment: I just went to this on my phone and something is definitely wrong.

Comment: all li elements are showing in mobile, so the code isnt working properly. Only 3 should show via mobile